# Xamarin iOS: How to change the color of a UIImage pixel by pixel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiimage

Sorry if this has already been answered somewhere but I could not find it.

Basically, I am receiving a QR code where the code itself is black and the background is white (this is a UIImage). I would like to change to the color of the white background to transparent or a custom color and change the QRCode color from black to white. (In Xamarin iOS)

I already know how to get the color of a specific Pixel using the following code:

```
static UIColor GetPixelColor(CGBitmapContext context, byte[] rawData, 
UIImage barcode, CGPoint pt)
    {
        var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(rawData);
        UIColor resultColor = null;
        using (context)
        {
            context.DrawImage(new CGRect(-pt.X, pt.Y - barcode.Size.Height, 
            barcode.Size.Width, barcode.Size.Height), barcode.CGImage);
            float red = (rawData[0]) / 255.0f;
            float green = (rawData[1]) / 255.0f;
            float blue = (rawData[2]) / 255.0f;
            float alpha = (rawData[3]) / 255.0f;
            resultColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(red, green, blue, alpha);
        }

        return resultColor;
    }
```

This is currently my function:

```
    static UIImage GetRealQRCode(UIImage barcode)
    {
        int width = (int)barcode.Size.Width;
        int height = (int)barcode.Size.Height;
        var bytesPerPixel = 4;
        var bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
        var bitsPerComponent = 8;
        var colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB();
        var rawData = new byte[bytesPerRow * height];

        CGBitmapContext context = new CGBitmapContext(rawData, width, 
        height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, 
        CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast);

        for (int i = 0; i < rawData.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bytesPerRow; j++)
            {
                CGPoint pt = new CGPoint(i, j);
                UIColor currentColor = GetPixelColor(context, rawData, 
                barcode, pt);
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone know how to do this ? 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not actually need access to the individual pixels but the end result only, using `CoreImage` pre-exisitng filters you can first invert the colors and then use the black pixels as an alpha mask. Otherwise see my other answer using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` and pointers.

```
using (var coreImage = new CIImage(ImageView1.Image))
using (var invertFilter = CIFilter.FromName("CIColorInvert"))
{
    invertFilter.Image = coreImage;
    using (var alphaMaskFiter = CIFilter.FromName("CIMaskToAlpha"))
    {
        alphaMaskFiter.Image = invertFilter.OutputImage;
        var newCoreImage = alphaMaskFiter.OutputImage;
        var uiimage = new UIImage(newCoreImage);

        imageView2.Image = uiimage; // Do something with your new UIImage
    }
}
```

The plus side is this is blazing fast ;-) and the results are the same:

[image]

If you need even faster processing assuming you are batch converting a number of these images, you can write a custom `CIKernel` that incorporates these two filters into one kernel and thus only process the image once.

Comment: First of all, thank you sooo much for your answers ! I do not need to access every individual pixel :) I would like to use the code your provided above since, as you said, it will be faster and more optimized. My issue is that I am receiving the UIImage directly and it only has a CGImage as it's base (the CIImage is null), is there a way to covert it so that I have my Image as a CIImage ? Thanks again !

Comment: @Praestolatio You can create a `CIImage` by passing it a `UIImage` (it has many different constructors). i.e. `var coreImage = new CIImage(aUIImageObject));`

Comment: My apologies, I had not seen the constructor in your solution. My issues seems to come from this line of code:    return ImageSource.FromStream(() => theQRCode.AsPNG().AsStream()); where theQRCode is the UIImage that returned from your solution. Is it possible that a CIImage cannot be converted to a Xamarin.Froms ImageSource ? Thank you again

Comment: I got it to work, from what I understood from Apple's documentation, a CIImage is not an actual image (as it is not rendered yet). Therefor I had to use the CIImage to recreate a UIImage :) Thank you again for all your assistance ! Couldn't of done it without ya

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your `UIImage` is backed by a `CGImage` (and not a `CIImage`):

```
var cgImage = ImageView1.Image.CGImage; // Your UIImage with a CGImage backing image

var bytesPerPixel = 4;
var bitsPerComponent = 8;
var bytesPerUInt32 = sizeof(UInt32) / sizeof(byte);

var width = cgImage.Width;
var height = cgImage.Height;

var bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * cgImage.Width;
var numOfBytes = cgImage.Height * cgImage.Width * bytesPerUInt32;

IntPtr pixelPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
try
{
    pixelPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)numOfBytes);

    using (var colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB())
    {
        CGImage newCGImage;
        using (var context = new CGBitmapContext(pixelPtr, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast))
        {
            context.DrawImage(new CGRect(0, 0, width, height), cgImage);
            unsafe
            {
                var currentPixel = (byte*)pixelPtr.ToPointer();
                for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                    {
                        // RGBA8888 pixel format
                        if (*currentPixel == byte.MinValue)
                        {
                            *currentPixel = byte.MaxValue;
                            *(currentPixel + 1) = byte.MaxValue;
                            *(currentPixel + 2) = byte.MaxValue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            *currentPixel = byte.MinValue;
                            *(currentPixel + 1) = byte.MinValue;
                            *(currentPixel + 2) = byte.MinValue;
                            *(currentPixel + 3) = byte.MinValue;
                        }
                        currentPixel += 4;
                    }
                }
            }
            newCGImage = context.ToImage();
        }
        var uiimage = new UIImage(newCGImage);

        imageView2.Image = uiimage; // Do something with your new UIImage
    }
}
finally
{
    if (pixelPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pixelPtr);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to implement your algorithm but to change a specific pixel color. Can you explain what is *byte.MinValue* and *byte.MaxValue* and the code seems to be very slow for a 600*600 png image

Comment: @OrcusZ byte.MinValue|MaxValue are statically defined constants (0|255) in the `byte` type. 600x600 is 360,000 RGBA8888 values that are being accessed in managed code, so of course this is not not going to as fast as processing it in a GPU CIKernel, or C or ASM...

Comment: @OrcusZ In just changing a single color, using a CoreImage CIFilter will be the faster way.

Comment: So I can use CIFilter to change for example red color to yellow one ? I already look a CIFilter but any of them seems to match my needs.... I will look again thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @OrcusZ You can create a custom kernel using `CIColorKernel` to takes two color params and swaps them on your input image.

Comment: Thanks I will look this

Answer (score -1):

Xamarin.IOS with this method you can convert all color white to transparent for me only works with files ".jpg" with .png doesn't work but you can convert the files to jpg and call this method.

```
 public static UIImage ProcessImage (UIImage image)
        { 
            CGImage rawImageRef = image.CGImage;
            nfloat[] colorMasking = new nfloat[6] { 222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255 };
            CGImage imageRef = rawImageRef.WithMaskingColors(colorMasking);
            UIImage imageB = UIImage.FromImage(imageRef);
            return imageB;
        }
```

Regards

[image]